# How do you select two different tags via xpath, both at different levels, when one of them is optional

Tags: xpath, confluence

I have a situation where the data is a mix of these format on the same page. In other words, some rows will show up as:

```
some lengthy XPATH_X uptill here:
<td/>
<td>
   I Need this element td
</td>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
```

and a few other rows will show in this format:

```
the same lengthy XPATH_X uptill here:
<td/>
<td>
    <span>
        I Need this element span
    </span>
</td>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
```

Please note that there are no differentiating attributes for each of the td tags. I need to select the second row (td) in both the cases.

I'm trying to catch both of the elements using the following xpath:

```
XPATH_X/*[self::td[position()=2] or self::td[position()=2]/span]
```

I tried this out on the page but for some reason it doesn't select anything.

Can someone please help me out with this? I've spent more than 2 hours on this already.

Comment: @Aaron Woiked poifectly! ^_^ Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ! I've added an answer, please make sure the third test case works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `XPATH_X/td[2]//text()` to retrieve the text whether it's at the root of the `td` or in a child tag

You can test it [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/469b33c2db53eb41fbfd8138f67c19c2) ; in this test I retrieve three results :

- the text inside a `span` inside a `td`
- the text at the root of a `td`
- both the texts at the root of a `td` and inside the enclosed `span` (if this doesn't work for you and the text of the `td` should be retrieved only if there's no `span`, use `XPATH_X/td[position()=2 and not(./span)]/text() | XPATH_X/td[2]/span/text()` instead)

To retrieve the elements containing text nodes rather than the text node themselves, you can use the following :

```
XPATH_X/td[2]//self::node()[text()]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work in the final code. The problem is that I'm using element.find_element_by_xpath(your solution) and this fails because we are returning back some text. I actually need to select the elements instead of their texts. :( I've updated my question with this info.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to modify your answer so that we're selecting the element instead of the text?

Comment: @Mugen can your try `/root/td[2]//self::node()[text()]` ? it sould return every node that contains text under the `td` (`td` included). I'll update the answer if you confirm it works.

Comment: Woiked poifectly again! Woohoo!

Comment: Nice :) Glad I could help !